# PhpmyAdmin do not display one table's data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry if it sounds like a very basic question but I didn't find any thing like this in site and google couldn't show me the answer.

I have a table in my database that have this strucure :

[image: table structure]

And these indexes :

[image]

It seems some thing is wrong in this table because I can't `SELECT` data from this table, inside some `PHP` code and even in `phpmyAdmin`.

There was duplicated indexes in this and I did drop them but still I have problem with it.

I did `OPTIMIZEd` table but still can't select data.

When I click on the icon to show this table(`general`)table structure, it's fine or when I try to select another table in the database, it's cool, but this table(`general`) seems to be locked or do nor work correctly.

Do you know what's wrong and how fix this?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? Can you reproduce this problem on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net choosing the latest stable version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Thanks for reply. Version : `3.5.8.2` based on `phpmyAdmin` first page. I'm not familiar with this site, trying to...

Comment: Click on your db name to show the list of tables, then tick the checkbox for this table and at the bottom, "With selected > Repair table".

Comment: I repaired table, but didn't help...

Comment: Try asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/